# How to change axis order from graph plotted using crosstab .plot() in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

These are my codes to plot a 2-line graph using crosstab .plot() from dataframe in pandas. However, the axis order is wrong and I want to order it from Monday to Sunday. I sorted the logData dataframe to unauthorizedAccess and used that for crosstab. Is there any way to do it?

I included the codes, dataframe and the plot.

unauthorizedAccess = logData.loc[logData['Access Type'] == 'Unauthorized']
pd.crosstab(unauthorizedAccess['Day'], unauthorizedAccess['Month']).plot()

[logData Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wEsJ.png)
[crosstab .plot() graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhsYN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert names of days to [ordered categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html):

```
unauthorizedAccess = logData.loc[logData['Access Type'] == 'Unauthorized'] 
names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
unauthorizedAccess['Day'] = pd.Categorical(unauthorizedAccess['Day'],
                                           categories=names, 
                                           ordered=True)
pd.crosstab(unauthorizedAccess['Day'], unauthorizedAccess['Month']).plot()
```

Or use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
unauthorizedAccess = logData.loc[logData['Access Type'] == 'Unauthorized'] 
names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
pd.crosstab(unauthorizedAccess['Day'], unauthorizedAccess['Month']).reindex(names).plot()
```

Comment: Works perfectly for both methods! Thank you!